# Оборудованы - чем?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте!

Слова "оборудовано", "оборудование" согласовываются с творительным падежом, верно?
Например: помещение оборудовано шкафчиками; НО не: в помещении оборудованы шкафчики.

Оборудование шкафчиками должно предусматриваться...
НО не: оборудование шкафчиков должно предусматриваться...

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По мне,так: "Помещения 1-4-х классов должны быть оборудованы шкафчиками-ячейками"(какбэ обеспечены инвентарем для какого-либо применения).Тогда "При проектировании зданий,оборудование помещений индивидуальными шкафчиками-ячейками,должно предусматриваться(быть предусмотренным) и для учащихся 5-11-х классов"
Не претендуя на истинность,чисто интуитивно)

Answer (score 0):

Все приведенные вами варианты допустимы.
Оборудование действительно управляет творительным падежом дополнения, но в предложении *В помещении обородованы шкафчики* "шкафчики" - подлежащие, "оборудованы" - сказуемое.

В отношении другого второй части, там другой смысл. "Оборудовние шкафчиков" одзначает не установку шкавчиков (в помещинии, например), а оборудование самих шкафчиков (полками, например).

Имейте ещё в виду, что слово "оборудование" здесь использовалось только в значении "действие пл глаголу оборудовать", есть же еще основное значение - предметы оборудования, то чем оборудуется что-либо. В последнем случае правила управления другие.

Comment: Все же я не поняла, верен ли вариант "помещение оборудовано шкафчиками"?  При чем тут подлежащее и сказуемое? :)

И во втором случае слово "оборудование" все же выступает в значении "установка".

Вот контекст: "В помещениях 1-4-х классов должны быть оборудованы шкафчики-ячейки. При проектировании зданий оборудование индивидуальных шкафов-ячеек должно предусматриваться и для учащихся 5-11-х классов".